# Swift: UICollectionView & UIImage fatal error: Array index out of range

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage

Hi Im new to swift and need some help thank you. The program worked once, tried to run it again then it crashed.  The items are in the array when I debugged but when I try to display the images I get the fatal error.

```
    // Get Brands
    func getBrand () {

        // Create PFQuery
        var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "BrandInfo")

        // Call findobjects
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            // refresh array
            self.brands = [String]()
            self.pics = [UIImage]()

            // loop through array
            for brandObject in objects! {

            // get PFObjects
            let brandName:String? = (brandObject as! PFObject)["Name"] as? String

                if brandName != nil {
                    self.brands.append(brandName!)

                }

            let brandPicture = brandObject["Image"] as! PFFile
                brandPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                    if(error == nil){

                    let brandImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        self.pics.append(brandImage)

                        println(self.pics.count)
                    }
                })

    }
        // Refresh CollectionView
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

}

```
// Setting up collection view
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.brands.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell:collectionViewCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! collectionViewCell

    // Get elements
    let picToDisplay:UIImage? = pics[indexPath.row]  // this is the error line
    let dataToDisplay:String = brands[indexPath.row]

    let imageView:UIImageView? = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UIImageView


    // Set labels
    cell.brandImage.image = picToDisplay
    cell.brandLabel.text = dataToDisplay


    return cell

}
```

///////////////////////////////

struct brandCollection {

```
    var brandText:[String] = [String]()
    var brandImage:[UIImage?] = [UIImage]()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `brands.count` items, and you need `brand.count` images. But you are using a different array `pics` which will fail if it has less elements than `brands`. Looking at your code, there are several possibilities why this could happen.

This is bad design. You should have a data array that encapsulates all the information you need. Each image should be connected to its object (the brand), not held in some other array.

Comment: thank you for your response. Im not even sure how to do that yet, example ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Sorry, but you have to write your own code ;-). Give your brand class an attribute `image` and store the image there.

Comment: I was referring to a youtube video or something but thank you anyways

Comment: what about changing it to a struct and save the data. ive updated the code

Comment: You could make a class called Brand with variables name: String? and Image: UIImage? and create an array holding Brand (instances of your custom class). Then load your collectionView from that. This is one way of doing what Mundi proposes.